# Displaying multiple images inline

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I'm having an issue displaying these 4 images as the result is quite confusing from the following code:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():

    path = r"data/dogscats1/pupper"
    path1 = r"data/dogscats1/test1"
    path2 = r"data/dogscats1/peeps"
    path3 = r"data/dogscats1/pupper"

    imgpath1 =  path + "cat.jpg"
    imgpath2 =  path1 + "01.jpg"
    imgpath3 =  path2 + "001.jpg"
    imgpath4 =  path3 + "dog.jpg"

    img1 = cv2.imread(imgpath1, 1)
    img2 = cv2.imread(imgpath2, 1)
    img3 = cv2.imread(imgpath3, 1)
    img4 = cv2.imread(imgpath4, 1)





    titles = ['Kitty', 'Original','Jumble', 'Pupper']
    images = [img1, img2, img3, img4]

    for i in range(4):
        plt.subplot(4,4,i+1)
        plt.imshow(img[i])
        plt.title(titles[i])
        plt.xticks([])
        plt.yticks([])

    plt.show()  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

Any help with displaying the images properly would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `plt.imshow(img[i])` is searching through the `list` called `img` which hasn't been defined yet, the images are currently stored in the list called `images` so you just need to change this line to;

`plt.imshow(images[i])`

and it will instead return what you need!

Comment: Thanks for the heads up but unfortunately this displays the exact same result as above

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot view images, can you post the result as a code snippet?

Comment: Sorry not sure how to do that how do I go abour doing that?

Comment: Also make sure you are in the correct working directory when executing, otherwise define the whole route in the path `path = r"C:/Users/username/data/dogscats1/pupper"`

Comment: Yes I am definitely in the right directory thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Basically it is displaying the images as single column lines rather than full images and I'm not quite sure how to fix it

Comment: OK I managed to see the image. However I did find a snippet that states that in order to use `imshow` you need to also use `cv2.waitKey(0)`

Comment: I put that into the function but it did not resolve the issue

Comment: Another suggestion - try this; `for i in range(4):
        plt.subplot(4,4,i+1)
        plt.imshow(titles[i], img[i])
        plt.xticks([])
        plt.yticks([])`

Comment: TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Comment: Sorry Oisin, my knowledge of cv2 isn't broad enough to help further, I'm now just reading the documentation but it's difficult to debug without being able to run the script.

Comment: Hmmm... just noticed (last attempt) I think you are searching within the 'list' `img`. Try this;
`plt.imshow(f'img{i}')`

OR

`plt.imshow(images[i])`

Comment: TypeError: Image data cannot be converted to float

Comment: The second option worked I have no idea why but thank you very much my man

Comment: If you edit your answer to display that I will upvote it so other people can see it in future for help :))